# Spring Boot application - HikariPool being created for each thread

Tags: java, spring-boot, hikaricp

I have a [Spring Boot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework#Spring_Boot) 2 application which uses the default Hikari connection pool.

I noticed that each thread creates a new connection pool object.

At the startup:

```
2019-11-13 10:52:26.693  INFO 79393 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-11-13 10:52:26.866  INFO 79393 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
```

Then for each request:

```
2019-11-13 10:53:24.165  INFO 79393 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Starting...
2019-11-13 10:53:24.169  INFO 79393 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Start completed.
2019-11-13 11:02:00.835  INFO 79393 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-3 - Starting...
2019-11-13 11:02:00.839  INFO 79393 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-3 - Start completed.
```

and so on.

Is this behaviour by design or did I misconfigure something?

I'm using a `JdbcClientDetailsService` and `JdbcTokenStore`, so each request needs to fetch information from the `data` source.

Here's the authentication server configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resource.id}")
    private String resource_id;

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resource.jwt.key-value}")
    private String signingKey;

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.client-id}")
    private String my_trusted_client_id;

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.client-secret}")
    private String secret;

    @Value("classpath:kcc.jks")
    private Resource keystore;

    @Value("${server.ssl.key-alias:keycrime}")
    private String keypair;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

    @Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        final JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        KeyStoreKeyFactory keyStoreKeyFactory = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(keystore, signingKey.toCharArray());
        converter.setKeyPair(keyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair(keypair));
        return converter;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) {
        security.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
            .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

        clients.jdbc(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
                .withClient(my_trusted_client_id)
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
                .authorities("ROLE_SYS_ADMIN", "ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_DBA")
                .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                .resourceIds(resource_id)
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(60 * 60 * 8)
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(60 * 60 * 24 * 365)
                .secret(secret);

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {

        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter())
                .reuseRefreshTokens(false)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);

    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {

        DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();

        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        defaultTokenServices.setReuseRefreshToken(false);

        return defaultTokenServices;
    }
```

Here's the MySQL configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "...")
public class MySqlConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("...");
        em.setPackagesToScan("...");
        em.setDataSource(dataSource);
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
        return em;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager manager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        manager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManager().getObject());
        return manager;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate () {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

}
```

**Edit 3**:

I found that in Spring Boot 2 the default scope for Hikari data source is refresh when Spring Cloud is configured. Also I found the follow configuration in the code (I'm investigating code written in part by someone else):

```
beanFactory.registerScope("refresh", new SimpleThreadScope());
```

so this explain this behaviour. But there could be a reason why adding this configuration?

Comment: You misconfigured something. So how did you configure it?

Comment: Edited adding authorization server configuration

Comment: That's nice, but since the problem is with the connection pool, how about including the connection pool configuration instead.

Comment: There's actually not much configured on the connection pool side as Hikari is the default for Spring Boot 2 and the dataSource is always autowired. Anyway I added the MySql configuration I'm using.

Comment: But the default configuration isn't "create a connection pool for each thread", which doesn't even make sense, so something's getting misconfigured. You could disable the autoconfig and configure it yourself to see if there's other things that try to mess with the pool. The behaviour sounds like the bean were stereotype or request scoped, and that shouldn't just happen.

Comment: Debugging this behaviour I noticed that the "dataSource" bean is requested in the "refresh" scope that apparently implies a thread scope and the creation of a new pool for each thread. But how is this behaviour driven?

Comment: The refresh scope seems to be `spring-cloud` related things, that's out of my area of expertise. But if you don't need spring cloud, remove it and see what happens.

Comment: @Kayaman thank you for your help. I found that refresh is the default scope of the Hikari data source. Please have a look to my edit 3.